# Connecting Rows of Array to Date and Time formate

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime, concatenation, extract

Im New to Python, it sounds easy- but i cant solve it, nether find a resolution with similar questions.

I have an Array where every row has one value ((...), Hour, Min., Sec., (...) ,D, M, Y) - Example:

```
arr = np.array([x, x,0, 0, 3, x, x,10, 8, 2022])
```

How can I conect the rows by ID to create an Data.frame of Date and Time in the formate:

```
Date:              Time:
YY/DD/MM           HH:MM:SS
```

So in my example i want to create an dataframe like:

```
Date:              Time:
2022/08/10         00:00:03
```

I was trying to use merge or concat, but only reach to the output:

[2022.10.8],[0.0.3]

High Thanks for any ideas! :  )

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
arr = np.array([-1, -1, 0, 0, 3, -1, -1, 10, 8, 2022])

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        pd.to_datetime(
            f"{arr[-1]}/{arr[-2]}/{arr[-3]} {arr[-8]}:{arr[-7]}:{arr[-6]}"
        )
    ],
    columns=["DateTime"],
)

df["Date"] = df["DateTime"].dt.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")
df["Time"] = df["DateTime"].dt.time
df = df[["Date", "Time"]]

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
         Date      Time
0  2022/08/10  00:00:03
```

Comment: Hey Andrej, looks so easy and obvious now, thank you!

Comment: But one question: is there a reason why you first created them into one column ("DateTime") and then separated it, instead of creating directly two columns like columns=["Date", "Time"] ?

Comment: @MaryJule I use the function `pd.to_datetime` - this function also checks if the date/time is correct. Also, when you have datetime object you can use various function (using the `.dt` accessor) which is convenient.